# Limiting the number of search suggestions, android

Tags: android, search, max, limit, search-suggestion

Is there a way to limit the number of displayed suggestions, when using the search interface with custom search suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple actually.

Firstly in your `ContentProvider`, define a variable to have a reference to:

```
public static final String LIMIT_PARAMETER = "LIMIT";
```

In your `Cursor query` @Override of the provider define something to hold your limit value

```
String limit = uri.getQueryParameter(LIMIT_PARAMETER);
```

Then pass the `limit` to the `SqliteQueryBuilder`:

```
final Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, limit);
```

You can then use it with a `contentResolver` like so:

```
getContentResolver().query( 
    SOME_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(
        YourContentProvider.LIMIT_PARAMETER, yourLimit).build(), 
    mSuggestionProjection, mSelection,
    filterArgArray, ORDER_BY );
```