# Is there a way to limit the number of displayed suggestions when using the default search suggestions adapter?

Tags: android, searchview

Is there a way to limit the number of displayed suggestions when using the default search suggestions adapter as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html)?

Comment: I think you should check the number of existing suggestions in SearchRecentSuggestions and if the number exceeds the limit, do not save the query to your suggesstion.

Comment: @AmbujKathotiya that wouldn't be useful since after a while it will no longer save the most recent searches. It doesn't answer the question either: I want to limit the number of suggestions _displayed_ not the number of suggestions being saved. Very different things.

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28068981/1649353

Comment: @AmbujKathotiya that answer you linked is about _custom_ adapters. My question is about the default suggestions adapter. I came upon that answer myself in my own googling. Please read the question carefully before posting. No points are given just for posting anything regardless of its relevance/usefulness.